# SQL query to exclude certain values from table

Tags: sql

[image]

Hi everyone I am in the process of building a room allocating system that checks if a room is available on a given date. There are about 20 unique room ids and I've just included as snippet of several above.

So for example if the user types in the date of 2012-01-01 I would want the **room_id** of 1 to be excluded from the results because as seen above it has been already booked for that date.

In a sense any match found between the user's in-putted date should cause the entire list of corresponding room_id's to be excluded from the list.

I used the below SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id
FROM room_booking
WHERE date_booked<>'$date'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work because although it excludes the result for a single row, it includes the rest of the results for a given *room_id*?

Comment: It's generally helpful to take your post with the particular database that you're using since every database supports a slightly different dialect of SQL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not tried this, but here goes

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id
FROM room_booking
WHERE room_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT room_id
     FROM room_booking
     WHERE date_booked = '$date'
    )
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id
  FROM room_booking rb1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM room_booking rb2
                    WHERE rb2.date_booked = <<date>>
                      AND rb2.room_id     = rb1.room_id )
```

or a `NOT IN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id
  FROM room_booking
 WHERE room_id NOT IN (SELECT room_id
                         FROM room_booking rb2
                        WHERE rb2.date_booked = <<date>>)
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have a column called `RoomID` I'm going to assume that there is a Room table with a corresponding column RoomID - this is probably a much better place to look for all rooms as you can't guarantee every room has a booking, and so can't rely on the booking table alone.

Then you can look up with a sub-query which rooms are booked on a date, then return all the RoomIds which aren't in that list.

```
select RoomID from Room
where RoomID not in
(select RoomID from room_booking
where date = @date)
```

Answer (score 2):

The above should work however may potentially become slow if a lot of rooms are added. You may want to consider a left outer join. It will typically be faster as the above will be performing sub queries i.e. For every room, requery the database to check if it has a value of this date which results in 40 * 40 checks each time this query is executed and will increase with the number of current bookings.

The below should be more efficient and *should* be valid on quite a few database platforms. Of course, this depends on how much the count of values may change if there are any string performance related items to consider...

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id
           FROM room_booking rb1
LEFT OUTER JOIN room_booking datecheck
             ON rb1.room_id = datecheck.room_id
            AND datecheck.date_booked  =  @date
          WHERE datecheck.room_id is null
```